# How insert new data to table and remove old without blocks users to read old data until end of process(MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-backups

The case:
Have huge table that every 24 hours need to delete all data and get new data instead.

How can I truncate this table and insert new data without block users to read data from this table?

What I thinking to do: (please write  which option better or suggest more proper option or standard solution)

Option1:

```
 1. insert new data to temp table
 2. drop old table
 3. rename temp table to the table name
```

Option2(problem: user cant access the table data in middle):

```
 1. truncate the table
 2. insert new data to table
```

Comment: Since you want an uninterrupted read access for your users, most of the data must be valid even before the replacement. Therefore I'd recommend that you selectively update changed data and insert new data instead of deleting the whole table.

Comment: But tis is very time consuming process compared to just truncate and insert

Comment: Why not `delete` & `insert` in a single transaction? That way other users won't see the changes until they are committed.

Comment: you mean: truncate table + insert into?but the insert action can tale more then hour -  can users access in the middle of the process to that table?

Comment: No. I mean **`DELETE`** as that is transactional whereas `TRUNCATE`is not (at leas in MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

```
1.insert new data to temp table
2.CREATE TABLE newtable select * from oldtable where 1=2
3.drop old table
4.INSERT INTO newtable select * from temp
```

Comment: here i am saying the temp table and your old table structure should be same so i said like above

Answer (score 1):

If you have any old data to keep:
Add a id column to your table. Fill it with a hash value computed by the value of all columns in a row. Load the new data into a temporary table. Update the old data with the changed and new rows.
Otherwise your first solution is the way to go, since the renaming of a table does not take mch time.

Comment: dont have any old data to keep